# Validation with custom method and adding a message to errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

```
class Confirmation < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_save :check_validity

  def check_validity

    case target
    when 'statements'

      statements = Statement.where(user: user, date: [start_date..end_date])

      total_earnings = statements.to_a.sum(&:earning)
      total_expenses = statements.to_a.sum(&:expense)

      unless total_earnings > 0
        errors.add(:earning, "Earning must be positive")
      end
      unless total_expenses > 0
        errors.add(:expense, "Expense must be positive")
      end

    end

  end
```

My data are just zeros, but if I try to save it I get no errors message and new record begin saved sucessufully. Where am I wrong?

Comment: as a side note, you should be able to use `statements.sum(:earning)`, and `statements.sum(:expense)`, would do the sum on sql level rather than fetching records and turning them into array then calculating the sum

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to replace the `before_save` with `validate`

```
validate :check_validity
```